# Need to get the array of objects from spring-boot to react table

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

OrderMed.js

```
export default class OrderMed extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Meds: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/v1/ivm/customer/inventory/medicines")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .then((data) =>{
      this.setState({Meds: data});
    })
```

console

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data:
->medicineList: Array(1)
   ->0: {name: 'Dolo', type: 'fever', price: 50, sellers: {…}}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
headers: {connection: 'keep-alive', content-type: 'application/json', date: 'Tue, 05 Jul 2022 18:46:55 GMT', keep-alive: 'timeout=60', transfer-encoding: 'chunked'}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
```

I need to get that medicineList array in the data, **.then((data)={this.setState({Meds: data});})** is not working for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  componentDidMount(){
axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/v1/ivm/customer/inventory/medicines")
.then(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
.then((data) =>{
  this.setState({Meds: data.data.medicineList});
})
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: I've been doing this at the beginning, but it doesn't until I restart the server it seems, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the value from the first `then`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/v1/ivm/customer/inventory/medicines")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      return response.data
    })
    .then(({medicineList}) =>{
      this.setState({Meds: medicineList});
    })
```

Comment: response is just to get the actual response from the api server, I need to get that data of medicineList which is a array of objects

Comment: See my edit. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Meds: data.data.medicineList worked